# React Redux - how to load details if the array is not yet obtained?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an app with redux and router where on the first load, all users are loaded. To this end, I've implemented a main component that loads the user when the component is mounted:

```
class Content extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.load();
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```

The afterwards, if the user chooses to load the details of one user, the details are also obtained through the same lifehook:

```
class Details extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getByUrl(this.props.match.params.url);
  }

  render() {
    const { user: userObject } = this.props;
    const { user } = userObject;

    if (user) {
      return (
        <>
          <Link to="/">Go back</Link>
          <h1>{user.name}</h1>
        </>
      );
    }
    return (
      <>
        <Link to="/">Go back</Link>
        <div>Fetching...</div>
      </>
    );
  }
```

Now this works well if the user lands on the main page. However, if you get directly to the link (i.e. https://43r1592l0.codesandbox.io/gal-gadot) it doesn't because the users aren't loaded yet.

I made a simple example to demonstrate my issues. https://codesandbox.io/s/43r1592l0 if you click a link, it works. If you get directly to the link (https://43r1592l0.codesandbox.io/gal-gadot) it doesn't.

How would I solve this issue?

Comment: This is as simple as either checking if the data hasn't been loaded, then loading it in this detail view and/or implementing logic such as loading indicators or redirects to control the user experience to avoid displaying detail views until the data has been loaded. If a situation exists where these detail views can be rendered before data is loaded, then that probably means you'd need to move the data loading to a higher level parent component to make it available as the application loads. What options have you tried for verifying loaded data? This is an issue of application structure.

Comment: I'd recommend posting this question on the [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There are a lot of people that could provide guidance on application structure and user experience as this isn't specifically an error. Realistically you have three approaches though. 1) Check in the detail view if all user data has been loaded and load it if it hasn't 2) For detail views, implement functionality to get detail data from your API or whatever 3) Move the data loading to the main application level so it's available as the application loads, instead of the list view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary of our chat on reactiflux:

To answer your question: how would you solve this? -> High Order Components

your question comes down to "re-using the fetching all users before loading a component" part.

Let's say you want to show a Component after your users are loaded, otherwise you show the loading div: (Simple version)

import {connect} from 'react-redux'

```
const withUser = connect(
  state => ({
    users: state.users // <-- change this to get the users from the state
  }),
  dispatch => ({
    loadUsers: () => dispatch({type: 'LOAD_USERS'}) // <-- change this to the proper dispatch
  })
)
```

now you can re-use `withUsers` for both your components, which will look like:

```
class Content extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (! this.props.users || ! this.props.users.length) {
      this.props.loadUsers()
    }
  }
  // ... etc
}

const ContentWithUsers = withUsers(Content) // <-- you will use that class

class Details extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (! this.props.users || ! this.props.users.length) {
      this.props.loadUsers()
    }
  }  
}

const DetailsWithUsers = withUsers(Details) // <-- same thing applies
```

we now created a re-usable HOC from connect. you can wrap your components with withUsers and you can then re-use it but as you can see, you are also re-writing the componentDidMount() part twice

let's take the actual `load if we haven't loaded it` part out of your Component and put it in a wrapper

```
const withUsers = WrappedComponent => { // notice the WrappedComponent
  class WithUsersHOC extends Component {
    componentDidMount () {
      if (!this.props.users || !this.props.users.length) {
        this.props.loadUsers()
      }
    }

    render () {
      if (! this.props.users) { // let's show a simple loading div while we haven't loaded yet
        return (<div>Loading...</div>)
      }
      return (<WrappedComponent {...this.props} />) // We render the actual component here
    }
  }
  // the connect from the "simple version" re-used
  return connect(
    state => ({
      users: state.users
    }),
    dispatch => ({
      loadUsers: () => dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_USERS' })
    })
  )(WithUsersHOC)
}
```

Now you can just do:

```
class Content extends Component {
  render() {
    // ......
  }
}
const ContentWithUsers = withUsers(Content)
```

No need to implement loading the users anymore, since `WithUsersHOC` takes care of that

You can now wrap both `Content` and `Details` with the same HOC (High Order Component)

Until the Users are loaded, it won't show the actual component yet.
Once the users are loaded, your components render correctly.

Need another page where you need to load the users before displaying? Wrap it in your HOC as well

now, one more thing to inspire a bit more re-usability

What if you don't want your withLoading component to just be able to handle the users?

```
const withLoading = compareFunction = Component =>
  class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      if (! compareFunction(this.props)) {
        return <Component {...this.props} />;
      }
      else return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
  };
```

now you can re-use it:

```
const withUsersLoading = withLoading(props => !props.users || ! props.users.length)
const ContentWithUsersAndLoading = withUsers(withUsersLoading(Content)) // sorry for the long name
```

or, written as a bit more clean compose:

```
export default compose(
  withUsers,
  withLoading(props => !props.users || !props.users.length)
)(Content)
```

now you have both `withUsers` and `withLoading` reusable throughout your app

Comment: thank you again for your time and the detailed explanation with examples!

Comment: my pleasure :-)